# Ajax request keeps giving me a 500 internal server error

Tags: php, ajax, database, server

my ajax request works fine when I run it on a local server but as soon as I had uploaded it to my server, nothing wants to work. My account registration page keeps returning: POST http://www.mydomainnottellingyou.net/php/registerUser.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Links to other files have been linked properly because it does work locally and also there is nothing wrong with the database login username and password. I have already tried using localhost and 127.0.0.1 for the host to connect to the database.

Here is the Ajax request:

```
var data = {
    username: registerUsername,
    password: loginPassword
};
$.ajax({
    url: "php/registerUser.php",
    data: data,
    method: "POST",
    success: function(response){
        if(response == "1"){
            window.location.replace("roomSelection.php");
        }
        else{
            $("#errorsDiv").html(response);
        }
    }
});
```

Then here is the php:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
        //Validate
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        if(strlen($username) >= 3 && strlen($username) <= 18 && strlen($password) >=6 && strlen($password) <= 16){
            //Check for special chars
            $allowed = true;
            for($i=0; $i<strlen($username); $i++){
                $charCode = ord($username[$i]);
                if(!(($charCode >= 48 && $charCode <= 57) || ($charCode >= 65 && $charCode <= 90) || ($charCode >= 97 && $charCode <= 122))){
                    $allowed = false;
                }
            }
            if($allowed){
                //Insert user to database now
                include "../lib/databaseHandler.php";
                $dbo = createDBO("chat");
                //Check if username already exists
                $statement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username";
                $bindings = [
                    ":username" => $username
                ];
                $query = executeQuery($dbo, $statement, $bindings);
                $numRows = getQueryRowCount($query);
                if($numRows <= 0){
                    //Create user
                    $statement = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";
                    $password = hash("sha256", md5($password));
                    $bindings = [
                        ":username" => $username,
                        ":password" => $password
                    ];
                    $query = executeQuery($dbo, $statement, $bindings);

                    //Get id
                    $statement = "SELECT userId FROM users WHERE username=:username";
                    $bindings = [
                        ":username" => $username
                    ];
                    $query = executeQuery($dbo, $statement, $bindings);
                    $rows = getQueryRows($query);
                    if(isset($rows[0]["userId"])){
                        $_SESSION["chatUserId"] = $rows[0]["userId"];
                    }
                    echo "1";
                }
                else{
                    echo "Username already taken";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

There is an include file there too (databaseHandler.php) which looks like this:

```
 <?php

    function createDBO($dataBase){ //Make Database Object
        if(strtolower($dataBase)=="chat"){
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/PeasFactory/Config/chatDbConfig.php";
        }
        return(new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbConfig["host"].";dbname=".$dbConfig["dbname"],$dbConfig["username"],$dbConfig["password"]));
    }

    function executeQuery($dbo, $statement, $bindings){
        if($dbo != null){
            $query = $dbo->prepare($statement);
            $query->execute($bindings);
        }
        return $query;
    }

    function getQueryRows($query){
        if($query != null){
            return $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }

    function getQueryRowCount($query){
        if($query != null){
            return $query->rowCount();
        }
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Is there a message in the logs that would help to find the error ?

Comment: I just found the error, I kept the include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/PeasFactory/Config/chatDbConfig.php"; which is a different path in my server than it is when I run it locally